# How to remove the last x zeros from a column dataframe in r?

Tags: r, zero

My data frame looks like this:

```
dput(tree)
structure(list(date = c(2.0220409e+13, 2.022041e+13, 2.0220411e+13, 
2.0220412e+13, 2.0220413e+13, 2.0220414e+13, 2.0220415e+13, 2.0220416e+13, 
2.0220417e+13, 2.0220418e+13), N = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
9, 10), NDVI = c(0.7192, 0.7034, 0.689, 0.6761, 0.6646, 0.6545, 
0.6458, 0.6386, 0.6299, 0.6231)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

In the column **date** I want to remove the last 6 zeros (which are repeated for all entries), how can I do that?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `tree$date / 1e6`?

Comment: ``tree$date=tree$date / 1e6`` works fine. thank you

Comment: @Maël post as an answer

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this?

```
options(scipen = 999)
library(dplyr)
df |> 
  dplyr::mutate(across(date, ~.x/1000000))
```